# Tcp socket using C (server)

Tags: sockets

I coded a program in C of a tcp socket but once executed, the server returns an error from the accept function but i can't find out why..

If you guys can help me, that would be appreciated. Also, if you have any advice on the way i programmed this, please feel free to tell me.

Here is my code :

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int listenSocket, status, socketClient;
  unsigned short int msgLength;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
  struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
  socklen_t clientAddressLength = sizeof clientAddress;
  char msg[101];

  //Test port number
  if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Usage : %s [NUMERO_PORT]\n",argv[0]);
      return 2;
  }

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;       // IPv4
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  // UDP
  hints.ai_flags = 0;     //Car on fait le test sur la meme machine

  if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 3;
  }

  if ((listenSocket = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo- 
       >ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
     perror("socket:");
    return 4;
  }

  if (bind(listenSocket, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) == 
   -1) {
     close(listenSocket);
     perror("bind:");
     return 5;
   }

  listen(listenSocket,5);

  int sizeOfSockAddr = sizeof(clientAddress);
  socketClient= accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
  if (socketClient < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Erreur accept\n");
    return 6;
  }


  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

  printf("Waiting for a client's request %s\n", argv[1]);

  while (1) {
   //some things
  }
}`
```

Comment: and what is that error message?

Comment: it's just "erreur accept" from my fprintf

Comment: You need to also print out the value of `errno`. Better still, print `strerror(errno)` to get a readable text version.

Comment: "Operation not supported"

Comment: Hmm... If I follow your code, you're trying to `accept` on a UDP socket. `listen` and `accept` are not valid operations on a UDP socket. So you're probably getting the error `ENOTSUP` (Operation not supported)

Comment: To expand... you can use (`listen` and) `accept` to accept a connection request on a TCP socket. But for UDP, each datagram stands alone and you will get the sender's address (via `recvfrom`) along with each datagram.

Comment: Damn I didn't see that one... Thanks that was a dumb mistake of me ! Did you notice some bad code or else ?